# identify if PDF has expiration date using python

Tags: python, pdf

So, I have a python/django system to upload documents.  My users want to block PDF docs that have an expiration date.  Does anyone have a good way in python to identify if an uploaded PDF has an expiation date?

Comment: Have you tried, I dunno, Googling it?

Comment: Yes, got lots of hits on how to add an expiration date.  Nothing on how to identify it.

Comment: Then keep searching. SO is not the right forum for this sort of question. You need to show some effort on your part.

Comment: @Jargosh Expiration dates are no feature of the PDF standard ISO 32000. Thus,  you are talking about some proprietary extension. Please at least describe the nature of that extension in your question.